# Minify html template string with javascript regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex, template-strings

In my project I am using a lot of JavaScript template string. After webpack compilation that is resulting in newlines, tabs and white spaces. How can I remove it with regex or any DOM API like `document.createTreeWalker`? I hope there would be easy regex to replace these.

Here is my source

```js
const employees = ['Rajkeshwar', 'Suresh', 'Manoj', 'Ramesh', 'Sudhir'];
const domStr = `
  <h1>Employee List</h1>
  <ul class="employee-list">
    ${employees.reduce((str, emp) => {
       str += `<li>${emp}</li>`;
       return str;
    }, '')}
  </ul>
`;
```

This is what I get after compilation

```js
var employees = ["Rajkeshwar", "Suresh", "Manoj", "Ramesh", "Sudhir"];
var domStr = '\n  <h1>Employee List</h1>\n  <ul class="employee-list">\n    '.concat(
  employees.reduce(function(str, emp) {
    str += "<li>".concat(emp, "</li>");
    return str;
  }, ""),
  "\n  </ul>\n"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following way to concatenate the string .

```
const employees = ['Rajkeshwar', 'Suresh', 'Manoj', 'Ramesh', 'Sudhir'];
    var domStr = `
    <h1>Employee List</h1>
    <ul class="employee-list">`;
    employees.forEach(function(employee){
                    domStr += `<li>`+employee+`</li>`; 
    });
    domStr = domStr + `</ul>`;
```

In `domStr` you will have your string .